# docker tomcat directory not found?

Tags: docker, tomcat8, ubuntu-16.04

I have run docker tomcat 8 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Docker version 1.12.0

> $ docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 tomcat:8.0
>       Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat Using CATALINA_HOME:
>       /usr/local/tomcat Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp Using
>       JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre Using
>       CLASSPATH:
>       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.958 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version: 
>   Apache Tomcat/8.0.39
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.960 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:
>   Nov 9 2016 08:48:39 UTC
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.960 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:
>   8.0.39.0
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.961 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:
>   Linux
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.961 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:
>   4.4.0-31-generic
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.961 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:
>   amd64
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.961 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.961 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:
>   1.7.0_111-b01
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.961 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:
>   Oracle Corporation
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.962 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:
>   /usr/local/tomcat
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.962 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:
>   /usr/local/tomcat
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.962 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.962 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.963 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.963 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.963 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.963 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.963 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.963 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.963 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded
>   APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.10 using APR version 1.5.1.
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR
>   capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
>   random [true].
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:03.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL
>   successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.1.0c  10 Nov 2016)
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:04.067 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-apr-8080"]
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:04.080 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-apr-8009"]
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:04.084 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in
>   690 ms
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:04.118 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting
>   service Catalina
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:04.118 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.39
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:04.129 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:04.656 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished
>   in 527 ms
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:04.657 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:04.732 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has
>   finished in 76 ms
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:04.733 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:05.177 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples has
>   finished in 444 ms
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:05.177 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:05.218 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager has
>   finished in 41 ms
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:05.219 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:05.245 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished
>   in 26 ms
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:05.250 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-apr-8080"]
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:05.259 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-apr-8009"]
>       18-Dec-2016 09:53:05.260 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1175 ms

and checked directory to /usr/local/tomcat but there is no the directory, where is the tomcat directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official Tomcat image documentation (On DockerHub), Tomcat location is indeed /usr/local/tomcat.

I've executed `docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 tomcat:8.0 /bin/bash` and I can confirm this is true. Please try executing the above command and check the results.

FYI, adding `/bin/bash` at the end of the docker-run command will execute BASH inside the container and let you interact with its contents.